# Trying to close a material snackbar after being called in a NGXS action does not work

Tags: angular, angular-material, snackbar, ngxs

After I call the snackbar from a NGXS action the snackbar does not close. Only after the specified milliseconds but not from the close 'action'

I tried closing it using the 'action' parameter and the 'ref.close()' method both did not work.

But if I call it normally from a component without using NGXS actions it closes like it is suppose to.

### NGXS action

> clicking 'Close' does not work. It stays open.
>
> > However if I click close and then click somewhere else that is not the button it closes right away

```
@Action(SomeAction)
  someAction(
    { setState, getState }: StateContext<SomeModel>,
    { payload }: SomeAction
  ) {
    ...
      if (payload.data.amount < 1000) {
         ...
      } else {
        this.snackbar.open('Error', 'Close', {
          duration: 4000
         });
        return;
      }
```

### Normal call from component

> clicking 'Close' works as intended

```
  test() {
    this.snackbar.open('test', 'Close', {
      duration: 4000
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Having run into this before - just subscribe to the dispatch (which returns when the dispatch has updated the state) and then do the snack bar.

Answer (score 0):

NGXS runs things outside of NgZone. To fix this:

```
constructor(
  private readonly snackBar: MatSnackBar,
  private zone: NgZone,
) { }

this.zone.run(() => {
  this.snackBar.open(...);
});
```